# BlackBerry textfield

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to develop an application in which text is displayed on a background image.

Text must be displayed on an image and when the background image is changed text also must change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achive above requirement first you need to set Background image for your MainScreen for this there are more methods one is to override paint method of MainScreen.
Example code:

```
Bitmap screen1=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Screen_1.jpg");
public void paint(Graphics graphics)
{
graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(),screen1, 0, 0);
super.paint(graphics);
}
};
```

After setting background image for screen you need to add LabelField or RichTextField to screen.

Example:

```
LabelField lf=new LabelField("text",Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH|DrawStyle.HCENTER);
add(lf);
```

When you need to change Backgound image set.

```
screen1=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("you image.jpg");
lf.setText("your labelfield text");
invalidate();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried as u suggested.I am able to display just one image with its corresponding text.I want to display different images one by one with their corresponding text.Can u pleas explain me how to do this?

Comment: you have to use timer task to change image and text after period of time